# Convert functionality of query to postgresql trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a table ctg:

```
CREATE TABLE ctg
    (
        id_ctg serial primary key,
        lft INT NOT NULL,
        rgt INT NOT NULL
    );
```

and a trigger which execute function after row is deleted:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ctg_el_del 
AFTER DELETE ON ctg
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_function();

CREATE FUNCTION trigger_function() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
/* deleting row and and his children */
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

for deleting rows and children in MySQL I used query:

```
SELECT @myLeft := lft, @myRight := rgt, @myWidth := rgt - lft + 1 FROM ctg WHERE id = 3; /* id of element which I want to delete */
DELETE FROM ctg WHERE lft BETWEEN @myLeft AND @myRight; 
UPDATE ctg SET rgt = rgt - @myWidth WHERE rgt > @myRight; 
UPDATE ctg SET lft = lft - @myWidth WHERE lft > @myRight;
```

How to properly use this query in trigger_function()?

I am using Nested Set Model: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: How to properly use this query in trigger_function()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much straighforward. You don't need a select to get the `lft` and `rgt` value from the deleted table. And you basically need to remove all the `@` from the variables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_function() 
  RETURNS TRIGGER 
AS $$
declare
  myleft integer;
  myright integer;
  mywidth integer;
BEGIN
  myleft := old.lft;
  myright := old.rgt;
  mywidth := old.rgt - old.lft + 1;

  DELETE FROM ctg 
  WHERE lft BETWEEN myleft AND myright
  AND id <> old.id; -- just to be sure

  UPDATE ctg 
     SET rgt = rgt - mywidth 
  WHERE rgt > myRight; 

  UPDATE ctg 
    SET lft = lft - myWidth 
  WHERE lft > myRight;

  return old;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

For more details on PL/pgSQL and triggers, please see the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

---

Btw: Postgres can handle an adjacency model quite well because it supports [recursive queries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html). Deleting, updating and inserting into an adjacency model is much more efficient. Retrieval performance with recursive queries is quite good (although probably not as good as with a nested set model). But the adjacency model also lets you defined foreign keys which is also a very big advantage.